# how to solve 404 error for the url download of a file to linux using wget?

Tags: linux, shell, url, download, wget

This is the url of the webpage where I'm trying to download from: https://www.oracle.com/de/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-x86-64-downloads.html

This is the file I'm trying to download:

```
oracle-instantclient12.2-basic-12.2.0.1.0-1.x86_64.rpm
```

I'm aware that I can't download from https://www.oracle.com/de/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-x86-64-downloads.html/oracle-instantclient12.2-basic-12.2.0.1.0-1.x86_64.rpm using wget.
this url returns a 404 error. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7623698/wget-cant-download-404-error), but it didn't help. How can I download this zip file otherwise? What am I missing here?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because a third party website having a broken link isn't a programming problem. You should address this to Oracle's own support channels.

Comment: @Quentin Sure, l wasn't aware that was a broken link problem.That helps too!

Comment: Its not actually a broken link. It requires logging in to be able to download it.  It's always such a gray area for me between what's a command line programming question and what's really just "how do you use linux".  But... easiest thing to do is download it with your browser (after logging in) and then copying it to your linux machine via ssh/scp/sftp.